# CORS error after deploying a typescript mern app on Vercel

Tags: typescript, cors, http-headers, mern, vercel

I am trying to deploy a MERN app written with typescript on Vercel.
I am trying to log in but I am facing CORS issues in production. The preflight request is working well.  Everyting was working fine in development. Does anyone could help me with this issue, please?

**Error in the console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUiH.png)

**Network tab**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyU5v.png)

**Preflight request**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HOnH.png)

```
const origin =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : 'https://tomflix.vercel.app'

const allowCors =
    (fn: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>) =>
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin)

        res.setHeader(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
            'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT',
        )
        res.setHeader(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Content-Type, Authorization',
        )
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            res.status(200).end()
            return
        }
        return await fn(req, res, next)
    }

app.use(
    allowCors(async (req, res, next) => {
        next()
    }),
)

app.use('/api/v1/authentication', authenticationRoutes)
```

I am trying to deploy an app on vercel but I am facing CORS issue. Trying to solve it

Comment: You should fix that 504 error first. Then, the required CORS headers will likely be present in the actual response.